# Connecting to a Windows IPython kernel from Linux

Tags: python, ipython

- I have a Windows machine where I start an IPython kernel (to do some stuff not possible on another machine).
- I have a Linux machine from which I would like to connect to the IPython kernel running on the Windows machine.
- I can SSH from the Linux machine to the Windows machine (using this solution: https://superuser.com/a/172299).

I have tried following: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh. Both the automatic and the manual solution gives the following:

"ERROR: Kernel did not respond"

Using the same solution, I can connect from my Linux machine to an IPython kernel running on a Linux server. Any solution to get this to work with Linux to Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the manual way on https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook%3a-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh once again and it worked. In detail:

```
windows-machine$ ipython kernel -f kernel-1234.json
```

---

```
linux-machine$ scp windows-machine:path/to/kernel-1234.json .
linux-machine$ cat kernel-1234.json
{
  "stdin_port": 55534, 
  "ip": "127.0.0.1", 
  "control_port": 58391, 
  "hb_port": 60540, 
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256", 
  "key": "fa461cf7-f078-4c22-909f-cfa7d2a30596", 
  "shell_port": 60159, 
  "transport": "tcp", 
  "iopub_port": 59207
}
linux-machine$ ssh -f -N -L 55534:127.0.0.1:55534
linux-machine$ ssh -f -N -L 58391:127.0.0.1:58391
linux-machine$ ssh -f -N -L 60540:127.0.0.1:60540
linux-machine$ ssh -f -N -L 60159:127.0.0.1:60159
linux-machine$ ssh -f -N -L 59207:127.0.0.1:59207
linux-machine$ ipython console --existing kernel-1234.json
```

Comment: Where is the `kernel-1234.json` located on windows machines?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need SSH to connect to a remote `ipython` kernel, regardless of whether it’s a `ipython` kernel running on `Windows` or `Linux` or `Mac`. What you do need is to have the Ip of the remote kernel visible to the terminal from which you are trying to connect from. Here are the steps:

1. **Find out the ip address of the `server` (the machine on which the ipython kernel is running i.e. where you want the computation to happen) and `client` (the machine from which you are trying to connect to):**

   1.1.    If you are on `Windows`, open up the command prompt and do a `ipconfig` to find out the ip addresses. If the `Windows` server has a direct Internet connection/lan connection, you should see a couple of ips like `192.168.57.1` and `10.2.3.64` and `127.0.0.1`.

   1.2.    If you are on `linux`, open up a terminal and type `ifconfig` or `ip addr show`. You should again see a couple of ips like `192.168.57.1` and `10.2.3.64` and `127.0.0.1`.

   1.3.    Test that atleast one of your `server` ip addresses is visible from the `client`: Ping your `server` from your `client`, using the command `ping`. `ping` will work on either Windows or Linux terminals. If you are running the windows/Linux as a VM or is behind a firewall, it is very much possible that your client or server is not visible from the other side. You don’t have to ping the ip address `127.0.0.1`. This is a loop back address, and is only visible from the same machine where you got this ip address from. For example if you ping `127.0.0.1` from the Windows machine, it will ping the same Windows machine. If your `client` and `server` instances are running on the same machine, then its fine to use this address. However, if your client or server is running on a VM or a different machine altogher, then `127.0.0.1` wont work.
2. **Start the remote kernel:**

   2.1.    Once you have figured out which ip address on the server is visible from the client, start a kernel on the machine using `ipython kernel`. The ipython kernel will startup and show that `To connect another client to this kernel, use:
   --existing kernel-1234.json

   2.2.    Locate the `kernel-1234.json` file on your `server` by importing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094772/4752883) 
   `In [1]: from jupyter_client import find_connection_file
   In [2]: find_connection_file()
   Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-1234.json'`
   This will work either for `Linux` or `Windows`.
3. **Start the remote client:**

   3.1.    Once you locate the file, copy it over to your server machine using `scp` in linux or `pscp` or `winscp` in windows [SCP w/ ssh: copying a local file from windows to a remote server using scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975798/scp-w-ssh-copying-a-local-file-from-windows-to-a-remote-server-using-scp/23412501#23412501)

   3.2.    Make sure that you are the same directory as the `kernel-1234.json` file.

   3.3.    Open up the `kernel-1234.json` file using vim or your favorite text editor. You will notice a line saying `"ip": "127.0.0.1"`. Change `127.0.0.1` the `ip` address from your server that is visible from the client, that you found in step `1.3` and save the `json` file.

   3.4.    Start up the remote kernel using `jupyter console –existing=kernel-1234.json`, while located in the same drive where `kernel-1234.json` is located.

If you have followed the steps above, you should now be able to connect to the remote ipython kernel regardless of whether the ipython kernel is running on `Windows`/`Linux`/`Mac`.