# Where is kernel-1234.json located in Jupyter under Windows?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

`IPython` has a useful function for locating the kernel connection file.

```
In [1]: from IPython.lib.kernel import find_connection_file
In [2]: find_connection_file()
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\me\\.ipython\\profile_default\\security\\kernel-1234.json'
```

What is the equivalent in `Jupyter` on Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Self answer:

```
In [1]: from jupyter_client import find_connection_file
In [2]: find_connection_file()
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-1234.json'
```