# Jupyter nbextensions does not appear

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried to install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions : http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Everything worked fine but when I open a notebook nothing changes. I can't see the new tool bar that I'm supposed to see.

When I reinstall the Extension, the process is the same (I don't have a message tellign me that the files already exists). I don't have an error. So I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 64):

Follow 3 steps: In Terminal

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main
```

after this you will see "Vaildating: ok"
Now you can open jupyter notebook you will see the require changes

Comment: It later worked for me.. the mistake was I need to enable it on the Jupyter notebook. See my comments answer with image below.

Comment: The first command works fine; the second gives a traceback ending with `Exception: Jupyter command 'jupyter-contrib' not found.` Looking at @rishijain's answer, I don't have the Nbextensions tab.

Comment: What is varInspector/main? Is it necessary to get it working?

Comment: I have previously installed it, however, I am facing the same issue. Extension menu not showing.
1. The first command shows,
Requirement already satisfied for all extensions i have previously installed.
2.Second one shows,

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.base'`

Answer (score 50):

**Update Jan 2021**
I was seeing this issue using the latest from pip packages.

Turns out it was related to:
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/the-static-notebook-js-mathjaxutils-js-is-missing/7303

Basically, jupyter-notebook moved a .js file in a recent update causing the extensions tab to no longer appear.

Reverting to an older version works-around the issue:

```
pip install notebook==6.1.5
```

Also note that a substantial number of the extensions aren't officially supported by the 6.x version. So you may be better off reverting to 5.x until your desired extensions are 'officially' supported:

```
pip install notebook==5.7.10
```

Comment: This worked for me-- thank you.  spend a whole day frustrated.

Comment: It seems `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` on GitHub has dead.

Comment: Thanks for saving me from wasting time on this issue

Comment: Reverting notebook to 6.1.5 worked for me in Feb 2023. Tried some other solutions from this post - without success.

Comment: This worked for me. FYI: It even worked with version 6.3.0.

Comment: obligatory "that worked for me", had this issue into ubuntu2204 WSL image.

Answer (score 11):

Following are the commands which installs the jupyter nb_extensions

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

The second command might give you below error:

```
jupyter contrib not found
```

Above command can be resolved as below:

```
- open cmd to install manually
cd .\Python\<your-python-version>\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
python application.py install
- Restart the jupyter notebook server
```

**Note**: Also make sure that your packages `jupyter` , `notebook` and your `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` are installed for same version of python (and same `--user` if you have installed all your packages with `--user` flag)

Comment: I also had the 'not found' error and your method to install manually worked for me. But I used --user in my pip install, so it was installed in '.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions' instead. Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me in the latest version of jupyter. Thanks! .

Comment: how can you verify that `jupyter`, `notebook`, and `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` are installed with the same --user?

Comment: @lauren.marietta- If all installed under same <user> , you will find your /home/<user>/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json will now have load_extensions section

Answer (score 7):

First, follow this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338184/2084944) (go to the update) to install the extension.
Then shutdown the notebook server.
Then type `$ jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main`.
If it says **OK**, you can start your notebook and should see the crosshair.

Answer (score 7):

try to run this

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

then relaunch the Jupyter notebook.
this might solve the problem as it did for me.

Comment: In my environment the "Nbextensions" tab was showing up, but the extensions were not. I didn't run this command because they said in the documentation it is not needed if you run the conda command `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`. After running the command mentioned in the answer the problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out ->

1)Open Anaconda Prompt.

2)Type in -

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

(if c is the default directory)

3)Proceed with the installation.

4)Exit the Anacodna prompt.

5)Relaunch Jupyter notebook.
(You will now see nbextensions tab)

Answer (score 5):

Following steps with Anaconda Prompt  ->

1)Open Anaconda Prompt.

2)Type in -

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

3. Enter 'y' for installation.
4. type in `jupyter contrib nbextension install --sys-prefix`

4)Exit the Anacodna prompt.

5)Relaunch Jupyter notebook. (You will now see nbextensions tab)

6. [Screenshot of my installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0RMW.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

1 quick info -
1. even after enabling nbextensions, from the notebooks tree page,
2. you need to activate it on your Jupyter notebook.
See below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***UPDATE, FEBRUARY 2023:***

I first installed nbextensions using `pip`. Then I couldn't run the second command `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` as the others and got the error `Exception: Jupyter command 'jupyter-contrib' not found.`

So, I tried installing using `conda` with this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

NOTE 1: I had to run my Anaconda prompt in "Administration Mode" in order to be able to install using `conda`.

After that I could run the second command:

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

And it's working now.

NOTE 2: I'm using the latest version of anaconda so I DID NOT need to revert my jupyter version as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65599505/18129386).

Answer (score 3):

**Update: August, 2023**

Here's what solved the problem for me:

```py
conda update --all
conda install -c anaconda notebook 
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

Then, `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` executes without error.

Now you can install and enable jupyter extensions (e.g. black) like this:

```py
jupyter nbextension install https://github.com/drillan/jupyter-black/archive/master.zip --user
jupyter nbextension enable jupyter-black-master/jupyter-black
```

Answer (score 2):

Running following command one by one !!!

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable spellchecker/main
jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/main
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this solution because it took me 20 minutes to figure out why my interface looked so different from all of the screenshots everyone else was posting. I hope it can prevent some other soul from making the same mistake I did:

I was running my Jupyter Notebook with the command `jupyter-lab` instead of `jupyter notebook`. I understand there are functional differences between the two, but in my case having spellcheck was much more important than any of the difference the two provided. As soon as I used `jupyter notebook` instead, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the notebook version to 5.6.0 worked for me.

`pip install notebook==5.6.0`

If this doesn't work for you, then return to your original version.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the highest voted answer to install the nbextensions but received an error when I reboot the Jupyter Notebook:

404 GET /nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main.js?v=20220513151408

It seemed that what I've installed can not be found by Jupyter Notebook.

After checking the detailed installation log in the terminal, I found Nbextension has been installed into the python2.7 directory:

./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter_contrib_nbextensions)

I am currently using Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook so I decided to uninstall what I have and reinstall Nbextension using pip3 instead of pip. Then I reboot Jupyter Notebook and saw the Nbextensions tab (next to the tab Clusters)!

In sum, based on my attempt, I would recommend using pip3 instead of pip to avoid an installation in Python 2 directory.

Answer (score 0):

My installed package version (windows 11):

```
notebook                          6.5.2
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions      0.7.0
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.6.1
```

Though I can not get the nbextensions menu tab out using the methods mentioned in the previous try outs of this post, I can still use the `jupyter nbextension enable <require path>` command in the `../python3/scripts` folder as following examples which I use frequently:

```
jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main
jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main
jupyter nbextension enable execute_time/ExecuteTime
jupyter nbextension enable hide_input/main
jupyter nbextension enable splitcell/splitcell
jupyter nbextension enable code_prettify/code_prettify
```

Then the variable inspector, table of contents, split cell, hide inputs and code prettify buttons appear in the notebook page. Other extensions can be tried replacing command's `<require path>` which can be found under the older version's notebook extensions tab that doesn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below commands are helpful to install nbextention

pip install notebook jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main

**Impotant Note:** make sure that packages jupyter , notebook and jupyter_contrib_nbextensions are installed for with same version of **python** and same --user flog
For example: In my system python3.7 and python3.9 were both installed but when I run pip3 install notebook jupyter_contrib_nbextensions , nbextension installed in python3.9 due to this jupyter contrib nbextension install --user not working but once is used pip3.7 install notebook jupyter_contrib_nbextensions for specific python3.7 then everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is this simple line of code:

`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions "nbclassic<0.5"`

No need to downgrade your jupyter notebook version.If you install a version of nbclassic>0.5 the nbextensions tab WILL NOT be visible when you run the jupyter server.Hope this helps you!Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Execute the following commands to install and configure `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` and `nbextensions_configurator`:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

If `nbextensions` is not displayed yet,

**Step 2:** Check whether the `notebook` version is higher than `6.1.5`. If it is higher, you can use the following command to reinstall it.

```
pip install notebook==6.1.5
```

I tested this method on Mac and Ubuntu can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the answers say, reducing the version of your notebook is the best solution, especially if you try the myriad of anaconda-promote commands.

Here is my version now, **notebook from 7.5.* to 6.4.8**

[image]

As text for easy copying:

```
IPython: 8.10.0
ipykernel: 6.19.2
ipywidgets: 7.6.5
jupyter_client: 7.3.4
jupyter_core : 5.2.0
jupyter_server : 1.23.4
jupyterlab: 3.5.3
nbclient: 0.5.13
nbconvert: 6.5.4
nbformat: 5.7.0
notebook: 6.4.8
qtconsole: 5.4.0
traitlets: 5.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't run the second command, `jupyter contrib nbextension install—-user,` after installing nbextensions using pip. It shows the error Exception: Jupyter command 'jupyter-contrib' not found.

So I ran everything under 'Administration Mode' from Anaconda Prompt
(Right-click on the Command Prompt or Anaconda Prompt in the search results.
Select "Run as administrator" from the context menu.)

1. Run `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`
2. Run `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`
3. Restart Anaconda

Perfectly done!!

Answer (score -1):

Change old path `notebook/js/mathjaxutils` to `base/js/mathjaxutils.js` to load the dependency correctly.

[image]

This solve my problem.

For details see this Github [issue](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/issues/125) about this bug.

Comment: No images of code please. Paste your code here.

Answer (score -1):

You can install or uninstall any extension you want manually if not shown the nbextensions tab in the Jupyter Notebook server after you are ensured you have installed jupyter_contrib_nbextensions and enabled the nbextensions configurator using the following commands.

#### install Jupyter Notebook extensions

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

#### enable the nbextensions configurator

```
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

#### To install extensions manually, You can use one of these following syntax

```
jupyter nbextensions enable/disable extension_name/extension_name
```

Or

```
jupyter nbextensions enable/disable extension_name/main
```

You are able to find and replace the name of your arbitrary extensions with 'extension_name' using [the list of provided nbextensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions.html%5D)

for instance, you can install or uninstall the following extensions as shown below

**Toggle all line numbers**

```
jupyter nbextension enenable/disable toggle_all_line_numbers/main
```

**Highlighter**

```
jupyter nbextension enable/disable highlighter/highlighter
```

**Variable Inspector**

```
jupyter nbextension enable/disable varInspector/main
```

**Hinterland**

```
jupyter nbextension enable/disable hinterland/hinterland
```

**Note:** After You got "Vaildating: ok", You have to shut down the Kernel to be able to use the installed extensions in Notebooks.

Comment: Although the extensions have been installed and activated and I get the validation success message. 

It doesn't work. With conda: 23.3.1,  jupyter_client   : 7.3.4 jupyter_core     : 5.2.0 jupyter_server   : 1.23.4 jupyterlab       : 3.5.3 nbclient         : 0.5.13 nbconvert        : 6.5.4 nbformat         : 5.7.0 notebook         : 6.5.2

Comment: Downgrading to  conda 22.9.0 jupyter_core  : 4.11.1 jupyter_server   : 1.18.1 jupyterlab       : 3.4.4  nbconvert        : 6.4.4 nbformat         : 5.5.0 notebook         : 6.4.12. NBextensions worked again. (With some warnings about  `template_path`)

Comment: Link doesnt work