# jupyter nbextensions not available after installation

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have recently uninstalled anaconda (individual edition), now I have installed it again. I have also installed the nbextensions [from here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), using the command

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`.

This should install all the nbextensions available (at least the last time it did so). But now, only a few nbextensions seem to be available - or at least they are not listed in the jupyter Nbextensions-Tab:

[image]

There should be much much more extensions.

I have also tried activating them separately via command line as [described here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/latex_envs/README.html), for example

`jupyter nbextension enable --py latex_envs`,

but that also did not work.

I am especially missing the *toc*, *collapsible headings* and *latex envs*. Does anyone have an idea how to get the extensions back?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a conda bug or something like that. Use:

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

After running this command, they will definitely appear.
Otherwise check this branch:
[Jupyter nbextensions does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647705/jupyter-nbextensions-does-not-appear)