# Incomplete nbextensions in jupyter notebook (only 5 extensions are showing)

Tags: jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Tried to invoke in the anaconda command prompt

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

But got this issue:

`This nbextension is enabled in the notebook json config, but doesn't provide a yaml file to tell us how to configure it. You can still enable or disable it from here, though.`

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to work around it and make yaml for it?

Comment: Refer to the below link. It worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743436/jupyter-nbextensions-not-available-after-installation