# How to correct loading errors of nbextensions in jupyter after conda updates?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Recently, I update my personal conda environment for Python and during the process updated conda package, but that started a series of problems that bring me to a series of uninstall and install packages, at the end I lost access to most of the nbextensions.

In my last loop, I installed miniconda + jupyter + jupyter_contrib_nbextensions and enabled nbextensions_configurator. But, when I get access to the tab configurator I got an error with all extensions. And by command line, I can infer that some paths are missing or there are conflicts with my current packages versions.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstalling everything but for now, I can't get nbextensions running with the usual commands that I used to use.

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

### Screenshot of tab configurator with errors in ALL extensions

```
[jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] error loading <extension>/<path>
```

[image]

### Environment

- Windows

```
(base) PS C:\Users\_me_> jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.12.0
ipykernel        : 6.19.2
ipywidgets       : 8.0.4
jupyter_client   : 8.1.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 1.23.4
jupyterlab       : 3.5.3
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.5.4
nbformat         : 5.7.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : 5.4.2
traitlets        : 5.7.1
```

```
(base) PS C:\Users\_me_> conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\_me_\miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\_me_\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\_me_\.condarc
          conda version : 23.3.1
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.8.16.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=11.0=0
                          __win=0=0
       base environment : C:\Users\_me_\miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\_me_\miniconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\_me_\miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\_me_\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\_me_\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\_me_\miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\_me_\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\_me_\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/23.3.1 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.8.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22621 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.3.0 libmambapy/1.4.1
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
           
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A few weeks ago through tab configurator in JUpyter, I could change settings for all nbextensions but now according to the versions of conda and Python I just can see the extensions in the tab but no use them.

I already check some questions in SO but the answers focus in the commands that I already have used. So I think that the problems is related to some current versions of conda, jupyter, or nbextensions.

- Question already asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647705/jupyter-nbextensions-does-not-appear)