# WIDGET ON JUPYTER LAB

Tags: widget, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to get a variable inspector widget to work on JUPYTER LAB, following, among others, the comments in this discussion:

[Variable Explorer in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718907/variable-explorer-in-jupyter-notebook)

I understand it works for JUPYTER NOTEBOOK (and I have been able to do that), but is there any way for this to be done in the JUPYTER LAB? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Jupyter Notebooks within [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) there has been a lot of discussion about implementing a variable explorer/inspector. You can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/443)

As of right now there is one Jupyter Lab extension in the works that implements a Spyder-like variable explorer. You can find the lab extension (with installation instructions) here: https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector

[image]