# How to use Variable Inspector in Google colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

How can I inspect variables within a Google's Colab notebook? I have tried adding the extension provided by this discussion ([Variable Explorer in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718907/variable-explorer-in-jupyter-notebook/41338184)) to access the variable explorer.
Although it has installed successfully, I was not able to use the extension. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This might be useful https://gist.github.com/Kreijstal/fb277585c6b31a4d82bb95cb91caf4e8

Comment: ^ doesn't work anymore.

Comment: works again, https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7873#issuecomment-747609102

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install extensions, although widgets don't yet work presently.

The relevant GitHub issue is:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/60

My recommendation is to describe your use-case there to help prioritize.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I am using google colab to develop a Machine Learning model but the data preprocessing becomes tedious on colab when the variable explorer is missing.