# Is there a way to use a variable inspector on Google Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

This is my first time working on Google Colab.
Is it possible to use a variable inspector in Google Collab ?
And if so, how ?

Thank you.

Comment: you can try making your own, see https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sYg2maTOT3GrCGS7R7WSxJcM3RsHjHAH#scrollTo=bn4q0OAA0ek5

Answer (score 7):

Update: as of 2022-02-22, Colab has its own variable inspector.
You can access it from the left panel.

[image]

---

Yes. This is how I do it.

Place this code into one code cell and run it.

```
from google.colab import output
#I don't know why nbextensions don't work with python3.6 
with output.temporary():
  !pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/Kreijstal/colab_inspector.git 
  !python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/blois/colab_inspector.git #yes, really.
  !jupyter nbextension install --py inspector

import inspector

# open a scratch cell (Ctrl+Alt+N)
# run there
# inspector.watch_globals()
```

Open a scratch cell (Ctrl+Alt+N)

On it, run

```
inspector.watch_globals()
```

And as you code on the left you will see the variables updated automatically on the right. You can even expand dictionaries and other stuff.

[image]

[image]

References:

- [How to use Variable Inspector in Google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505877/how-to-use-variable-inspector-in-google-colab)
- https://gist.github.com/Kreijstal/fb277585c6b31a4d82bb95cb91caf4e8

Keywords:
Google Colab, variable explorer inspector visualize