# Variable Inspector Jupyter Notebook - UPDATE 2022

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

There's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718907/variable-explorer-in-jupyter-notebook) on Stackoverflow on this. But it was asked 6 years ago, and the latest most upvoted answers are from 2017-2018.

Also, I am not very happy with any of the most accepted answers, one version has a few bugs, another one is old and clunky.

So I'm asking again, are there any more up-to-date versions of a (**simple**) variable inspector in Jupyter Notebooks?