# How to close kernel environment after calling "ipython kernel" in windows console?

Tags: python, ssh, ipython, spyder

I want to use spyder on my local machine but by using a kernel of a remote server. Achieving this requires finding the connection json file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094744/where-is-kernel-1234-json-located-in-jupyter-under-windows/35094772#35094772). The location of this file is required to transfer this json file via a SFTP client to my local machine, such that I can use it to connect my local spyder IDE.

The problem is that if I type "ipython kernel" in the console I get the info

> NOTE: When using the `ipython kernel` entry point, Ctrl-C will not work.

> To exit, you will have to explicitly quit this process, by either sending
> "quit" from a client, or using Ctrl-\ in UNIX-like environments.

> To read more about this, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2049

> To connect another client to this kernel, use:
> --existing kernel-somenumber.json

After entering this environment I'm somehow not able to do anything anymore - whatever I type in (%exit, quit) or trying to find the path to the json file as indicated above does not work either. Simply nothing seems to happen. Has someone else encountered this? Which command can I use in the console to quit this environment? The github link given above does somehow not help me either.

Comment: The quickest solution I found was to kill the relevant python process from the task manager.